# MysqlConnector issue with async await and multi thread

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, mysql-connector

I have this issue in production with MySQL connections where the connection is either being used or it's not opened error comes up frequently. I think when multiple requests hit the method then this issue is happening. I got stats from production were 80 different instances hit the Graphql method. I am using Sqlkata to make DB calls. When there are no parallel calls then it works fine.

## ConnectionManager.cs

```
 public IDbConnection GetConnection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_iDbConnection != null)
            {
                if (_iDbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    _iDbConnection.Open();
                    return _iDbConnection;
                }
            }

            if (_iDbConnection != null && _iDbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                // close the previous connection
                _iDbConnection.Close();
                // open new connection
                _iDbConnection.Open();
                return _iDbConnection;
            } 
                
            try
            {
                string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("seasonal");
                // Register the factory
                DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("MySqlConnector", MySqlConnectorFactory.Instance);
                // Get the provider invariant names
                IEnumerable<string> invariants = DbProviderFactories.GetProviderInvariantNames();

                var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(invariants.FirstOrDefault());
                var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                    conn.Open();
                    _iDbConnection = conn;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return _iDbConnection;
        }
    }
```

## Service (constructor)

```
 public OutboundRecordService(IConnectionManager connectionManager) : base(connectionManager)
    {

        IDbConnection connection = connectionManager.GetConnection;
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _logger.Error($"Connection is not open, current state: {connection.State}");
        }

        _queryFactory = new QueryFactory(connection, new MySqlCompiler());
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(OutboundRecordService<T>));
    }


   public async Task<CareMetx.Service.Models.PaginationResult<OutboundRecord>> GetAllByCriteria(OutboundRecordSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {

        try
        {
            // START - Test code
            var arrayTask = new List<Task>();
        
            int i = 10;
            for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
            {
                arrayTask.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDataFromDB(searchCriteria)));
            }
        
            Task.WaitAll(arrayTask.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
            return await Task.FromResult<CareMetx.Service.Models.PaginationResult<OutboundRecord>>(null);
            // END  - Test code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private async Task<List<OutboundRecord>> GetDataFromDB(OutboundRecordSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        Query dbQuery = _queryFactory.Query("SELECT * FROM OutboundRecords Where BatchId = 1");
        // Clone the query and get the total count
        var totalCountQuery = dbQuery.Clone();
        totalCountQuery = totalCountQuery.AsCount();

        // Log Record Count SQL
        LogSqlQuery(totalCountQuery);

        // Get the total record count
        var totalRecords = await totalCountQuery.FirstOrDefaultAsync<int>();
    }
```

## Exception

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which MySQL Connector library are you using? Oracle's Connector/NET fakes async operations. The open source MySqlConnector offers true asynchronous operations instead, and solves a lot of bugs Oracle has no intention of fixing

Comment: As for the "connection manager" class, that's a *major* bug. ADO.NET connections are meant to be opened right before use and closed immediately afterwards. Connection pooling ensures opening a new connection costs nothing, by resetting connections when `Close` or `Dispose` is called and putting them in a connection pool. You could use eg [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to replace boilerplate ADO.NET code with just `var customers=await connection.QueryAsync<Customer>("select * from customers where categoryId=@id",new {id=123});`,

Comment: `80 different instances hit the Graphql method` that's a *very* different question. Even if you use Dapper to replace your current code, that's still a lot of code to write for every entity. You can use a GraphQL library like HotChocolate [that integrates with EF Core directly](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/integrations/entity-framework), Your resolver code can become a one-line method `[UseDbContext(typeof(SomeDbContext))] public IQueryable<User> GetUsers([ScopedService] SomeDbContext dbContext) => dbContext.Users;`

Comment: If you use HotChocolate's EF integration, pagination, projection, filtering are provided out of the box on top of IQueryable. You only need to apply the correct attributes eg `UsePaging` to the resolver method. You can use both [connection and offset based pagination](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/fetching-data/pagination)

Comment: I am using HotChocolate's  library but not using any EF context. I am required to use direct SQL queries using SQlKata.  i am using https://mysqlconnector.net/ from nuget

Comment: Why aren't you using EF Core? Executing SQL queries the wrong way won't make your queries faster. `SELECT *` is definitely the wrong way because it loads all fields, whether the client requested them or not. If the client requests a customer's name only, why return the entire record? Besides, the code you posted is *way* too complicated and contains a lot of mistakes. In fact, none of the methods seems to be working - either they don't return a result, or they return the wrong result. You've spent a lot of effort trying to emulate what EF Core or Dapper already do

Comment: *All* you really need is to create a connection factory - that doesn't mean using ADO.NET's DbConnectionFactory. It means having a "something", either a `Func<DbConnection>` or an interface, that returns *new* `DbConnection` instances without trying to open them. That connection should be stored in a variable declared in a `using`, to avoid leaked connections. After that *use Dapper* instead of trying to hand-roll MySqlCommand instances. Dapper already does what you would do (execute a raw SQL query with parameters and map the results) and more. Less hand-written code means less bugs.

Comment: But again, why not EF Core? EF Core 6 will generate better queries than `SELECT *`, is already almost as fast as Dapper/ADO.NET, and actually *faster* if you compare `SELECT CustomerName` with `SELECT *`. Nothing prevents you from combining EF Core, Dapper or raw ADO.NET anyway. In fact, most applications use both, in different scenarios. Eg, EF Core for most entities, and Dapper/ADO.NET for specialized queries, eg reporting, or specific mutations. For example, EF Core makes it easy to update a complex object graph, but `UPDATE Customer SET Name=@Name where ID=@id` is better for small updates